# emacs - automatically split frames on creation

Tags: emacs

I almost always use Emacs in a one-frame, two-window configuration (that is, one OS window with two Emacs windows inside it).  I have the `default-frame-alist` set so that frames appear at the right size, but then I have to manually split them (with <kbd>C-x 3</kbd>).  Is there a way to tell Emacs to do that automatically when each new frame is created?

**EDIT:** If I do happen to create a new frame at some point, I want it to be split vertically as well.  Therefore, `(when window-system (split-window-horizontally))` in `.emacs` won't do the job, because it only applies to the *initial* frame.  What I think I need is a hook that runs in the context of each new frame *after* the `default-frame-alist` is applied.

Answer (score 5):

Just add

```
(split-window-horizontally)
```

to your `.emacs` file.

With `C-h k`  you can check which Emacs function is linked to your shortcut. It's very useful if you are not familiar good enough with Emacs functions.

Comment: This is a bit too indiscriminate.  For instance, I do not want this to happen if I'm running Emacs in a terminal (which I do do from time to time).

Comment: @zack its simple. put that into `if` like `(if (window-system) (split-window-horizontally))`

Comment: It took me a long time to figure out why I didn't like this answer, but I finally did; please see the edited question.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent from automatical vertical buffer splitting when e.g. visiting an item in a grep buffer the setting

```
(setq split-height-threshold nil split-width-threshold nil)
```

is useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you are asking for, but it's a nice way to get two windows side by side.

You can set the variables `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold`, to change the behavior of `split-window-sensibly`. This way every time a new window pops up, say by autocompletion or by pressing `o` in a dired buffer, the frame gets split horizontally.

```
;; only split horizontally
(setq split-height-threshold nil
      split-width-threshold 0)
```

New frames will still start with only one window, but the first time a new window pops up, you will get one window on the left side and another on the right side.